# Drag a div and see the item moving

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag-and-drop, drag

Right now I'm trying to achieve the drag and drop functionality.

I have this.

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag();
  drag.on('drag', function () {
    console.log("drag start");
  })
  drag.on('dragend', function () {
    console.log("drag stop");
  })

  selection = d3.select('.right.menu');
  selection.call(drag);
```

Which works, but now I want to see the div moving on the screen, right now I only get the consoles, how this can be done, or even better any guidance about how this method / event is named to do some research will be great.

**Update**

Current Solution.

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag();
  drag.on('drag', function () {
console.log(selection);
    selection.style("left", d3.event.x+"px").style("top", d3.event.y+"px").style("position", "inherit");
  })
  drag.on('dragend', function () {
    console.log("drag stop");
  })

  selection = d3.select('.right.menu')
  selection.call(drag);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of moving a div using css `position:absolute` and modifying the top and left offset according to the drag.

```
appdiv.style("left", d3.event.x+"px").style("top", d3.event.y+"px");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aema8m60/1/)

Comment: thanks, updated the answer with the current solution